# Summernote not working in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to use summernote for my rails web. And I follow the steps provided here https://github.com/summernote/summernote-rails/wiki/Image-File-Upload-to-Server But the text area using summernote don't display.
I use ruby 2.4.0 and rails 5. Can anyone help me?. Thank so much

gemfile:

```
gem "bootstrap-sass", "~>3.3"
gem "font-awesome-rails", "~> 4.3"
gem 'summernote-rails', '0.7.1.0'
gem 'codemirror-rails'
gem 'paperclip'
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require codemirror
//= require codemirror/modes/ruby
//= require summernote
//= require summernote/locales/ko-KR
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree.
```

form

```
<%= simple_form_for(@post) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :title %>
    <%= f.input :content, as: :summernote %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

thanks for your help. I've put your code to application.js but it's not working. Then I put it to application.html.erb like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
$('[data-provider="summernote"]').each(function(){
    $(this).summernote({ });
    })
});
</script>
```

It work. I can’t figure it out

Answer (score 0):

In your application.js file after the imports, you need to initialize the summernote. Just add this:

```
$('[data-provider="summernote"]').each(function(){
  $(this).summernote({ });
})
```

Or, if you want to code in coffeescript,

```
$ ->
  $('[data-provider="summernote"]').each ->
    $(this).summernote()
```

You can find this in the gem docs.

If you already put this code in the file, update your question.

Answer (score 0):

okay, this using gem summernote process

installation gem, if you want to used simple_form gem

Add the following gems to your application's Gemfile:

```
  gem "simple_form"

# This is the right gem to use summernote editor in Rails projects.   
  gem 'summernote-rails'
  gem 'codemirror-rails'

# You'll need to include the following dependencies of Summernote
  gem 'codemirror-rails'
  gem "font-awesome-rails"    

# To solve the problems on the turbolinks
  gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
```

And then execute:

```
bundle
```

Usage
First of all, the summernote editor works on Bootstrap and so it is assumed that you have already set it up.

In app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss,

```
// Bootstrap 

@import "summernote";
@import "font-awesome";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "codemirror";
@import "codemirror/themes/solarized";
@import "codemirror";
@import "codemirror/themes/solarized";
@import "NAME_FILE_css"; //EX:@import "courses" import courses.scss if requierd
```

In app/assets/javascripts/application.js, you should add the following:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require codemirror
//= require summernote
//= require_tree .
//= require turbolinks
```

create summernote-init.coffee on javascript folder and add this code:

```
$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->
 $('[data-provider="summernote"]').each ->
  $(this).summernote
   height: 300
```

important for render your content with style applied:

*simply adds the methode **sanitize** before calling the variable. example to display course with the applied style:*

In courses/show.html.erb

```
<%= sanitize @course.corps %>
```